# Display Second Menu when a Menu Item is selected in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, menu, shinydashboard

I have a shiny dashboard and in the sidebar I have two menus. The first has two items while the second has five.

When the dashboard loads the first item "Home" in the first menu is selected as default. When the second item is selected, the second menu is shown.

I've succeed in showing the second menu but the first menu goes back to the "Home" menu item. You can click on any of the items in the second menu just fine but the first menu always changes back to the home item when selecting the second item.  I want it to stay on the second item when that has been selected and basically use the two menus as if they were one.

I do not want however the second menu to be a sub menu as it is not.

Below is some dummy code displaying the problem.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue", title = "",
                    dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(id="fMenu", sidebarMenuOutput("firstMenu")),
                      sidebarMenu(id = "eMenu", sidebarMenuOutput("extendedMenu"))
                      ),
                    dashboardBody()
)

server <- (function(input, output, session) {



  output$firstMenu <- renderMenu({
    menu_list <- list(
      menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
      menuItem("2nd Item", tabName = "second", icon = icon("sort"))
    )

    sidebarMenu(.list = menu_list)
  })

  isolate({updateTabItems(session, "featureMenu", "home")})

  observeEvent(input$fMenu, {
    if(input$fMenu == "second"){
      output$extendedMenu <- renderMenu({
        menu_list <- list(
          menuItem("3rd Item", tabName = "third", icon = icon("sort")),
          menuItem("4th Item", tabName = "fourth", icon = icon("sort")),
          menuItem("5th Item", tabName = "fifth", icon = icon("sort"))
        )

        sidebarMenu(.list = menu_list)
      })
    }
  })

})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The re-rendering of the menu causes it to re-select the first tab. You can use the argument `selected` in your `menuItem` to keep the seond tab selected. However, in this case you should only have a single `sidebarMenu` and a single `sidebarMenuOutput`.

**Working example**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "blue", title = "",
                    dashboardHeader(),
                    dashboardSidebar(
                      sidebarMenu(id="fMenu", 
                                  sidebarMenuOutput("firstMenu"))
                    ),
                    dashboardBody()
)

server <- (function(input, output, session) {
  output$firstMenu <- renderMenu({
    menu_list <- list(
      menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
      menuItem("2nd Item", tabName = "second", icon = icon("sort"))
    )
    sidebarMenu(.list = menu_list)
  })

  observeEvent(input$fMenu, {
    if(input$fMenu == "second"){
      output$firstMenu <- renderMenu({
        menu_list <- list(
          menuItem("Home", tabName = "home", icon = icon("home")),
          menuItem("2nd Item", tabName = "second", icon = icon("sort"), selected=T),
          menuItem("3rd Item", tabName = "third", icon = icon("sort")),
          menuItem("4th Item", tabName = "fourth", icon = icon("sort")),
          menuItem("5th Item", tabName = "fifth", icon = icon("sort"))
        )

        sidebarMenu(.list = menu_list)
      })

    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @Nate Keep in mind that now every time you click on the second tab the menu will be re-rendered. If you only want this to happen once you should probably build another if statement.